How to show Visual Studio Code navigation history like in a browser?
Visual Studio Code adopts some useful features from browsers: Back and Forward buttons to navigate to visited locations (file, line). That is nice, but still lacking. In browser you can right click on the Back or Forward button to see all recent locations and jump several steps backward or forward.
Questions:

Does VS Code has this feature?
If not, is there an API via which I can write a VS Code extension to produce the feature myself?

More details: This ability would be very beneficial because I find that usually I navigate forward slowly, but need to go backward quickly, skipping 4-5 locations at a time.  Also, a list of locations is informative and gives an overview of how I have gone from file A to file G, for example.
I tried to look at keyboard shortcut list but haven't found it.
